# Calling a function from another location on a button click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, buttonclick

I need to call a function by clicking a button. The button is on an aspx page and the function is on a .js page.
This is the code I use for my button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBTNSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="buttonlink" 
 OnClick="lnkBTNSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="onBtnSubmitClick();">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
```

and this is my function:

```
function onBtnSubmitClick() {
    var startDate = document.getElementById('<%= txtATrendStartDate.ClientID %>').value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById('<%= txtATrendEndDate.ClientID %>').value;
    checkDateRange(startDate, endDate);
}

function checkDateRange(start, end) {

    // Parse the entries
    var startDate = Date.parse(start);
    var endDate = Date.parse(end);
    // Make sure they are valid
    if (isNaN(startDate)) {
        alert("The start date provided is not valid, please enter a valid date.");
        return false;
    }
    if (isNaN(endDate)) {
        alert("The end date provided is not valid, please enter a valid date.");
        return false;
    }
    // Check the date range, 86400000 is the number of milliseconds in one day
    var difference = (endDate - startDate) / (86400000 * 7);
    if (difference < 0) {
        alert("The start date must come before the end date.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Please note that the function is on an another .js page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the function in the other js file you have to include a reference to the js file on your page.

Example:

Put this in your head tag:

```
"script src="SomeOtherJSFIle.js" type="text/javascript"/script"
```

Comment: Include the mark-up brackets around the script tag.. I can't get that to display in the post :-) Once the reference is made you can call the function like any other function

Comment: thanx for the response...but the thing is nothing happens when i click the button...my button code is                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBTNSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="buttonlink" 
                                                        OnClick="lnkBTNSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="onBtnSubmitClick();">Submit</asp:LinkButton>..am i doing something wrong??

Comment: also when i keep the function in the same page..it works perfectly

Comment: Make sure you clear the browser cache in case an old version of the script without the method is cahed... Long shoot but worth a try :-). Otherwise the approach seem ok. All you have to do to reference the external script is to put the script tag in the head tag. Make sure the path is correct though...